# There are plenty of free memory, but exit "MemoryError" in Python

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory

My computer is with 64 bit operating system of Win7. The RAM is 16GB. I want to load 1 GB csv data into numpy.array. I monitored the resource and found that the program exited when the memory reached 8.56GB.

My Python version is: Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

The Code:

```
QA_file=open("QA_URLs.csv")
urlreader=csv.reader(QA_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

QA_HrefId=[]
QA_PostId=[]
QA_PostTypeId=[]
QA_OwnerUserId=[]
QA_ParentId=[]
QA_Href=[]
QA_CreationDate=[]

for line in urlreader:
    if len(line)==7:
        QA_HrefId.append(line[0])
        QA_PostId.append(line[1])
        QA_PostTypeId.append(line[2])
        QA_OwnerUserId.append(line[3])
        QA_ParentId.append(line[4])
        QA_Href.append(line[5])
        QA_CreationDate.append(line[6])


np_QA_HrefId=np.array(QA_HrefId)
np_QA_PostId=np.array(QA_PostId)
np_QA_PostTypeId=np.array(QA_PostTypeId)
np_QA_OwnerUserId=np.array(QA_OwnerUserId)
np_QA_ParentId=np.array(QA_ParentId)
np_QA_Href=np.array(QA_Href)
np_QA_CreationDate=np.array(QA_CreationDate)
```

The Exception Information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:Recommender.py", line 81, in <module>
    np_QA_Href=np.array(QA_Href)
MemoryError
```

Why did it report "MemoryError" while there are plenty of free memory?

Comment: Are you quite sure about the filesize? And what is the operation going on above this bit of code- it says line 81 here.

Comment: @optimist, the filesize of "QA_URLs.csv" is 976MB. The 81st line is: np_QA_Href=np.array(QA_Href). The purpose of this line is to convert list to numpy.array.

Comment: But the file's size on disk is distinct from it's size when read by python. Are you measuring the RAM your script is using?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan, I monitor the Windows Task Manager find that the program excepted when the script hited 3.5GB.